# Tab Escape Character?

Tags: c#

I'm just in the process of parsing some text and can't remember what the escape character is for a tab in C#?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Easy one! "\t"

Edit: In fact, here's something official: [Escape Sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)

Comment: Is this platform independent ? for example, Environment.Newline is platform independent while "\n" is not.

Answer (score 6):

For someone who needs quick reference of **C# Escape Sequences** that can be used in `string` literals:

> \t     Horizontal tab (ASCII code value: 9)
>
> \n     Line feed (ASCII code value: 10)
>
> \r     Carriage return (ASCII code value: 13)
>
> \'     Single quotation mark
>
> \"     Double quotation mark
>
> \\     Backslash
>
> \?     Literal question mark
>
> \x12     ASCII character in hexadecimal notation (e.g. for 0x12)
>
> \x1234     Unicode character in hexadecimal notation (e.g. for 0x1234)

It's worth mentioning that these (in most cases) are universal codes. So \t is 9 and \n is 10 char value on Windows and Linux. But newline sequence is not universal. On Windows it's \n\r and on Linux it's just \n. That's why it's best to use `Environment.Newline` which gets adjusted to current OS settings. With .Net Core it gets really important.