# how to find the numbers of tabs related to paragraphs with openxml in c#?

Tags: c#, ms-office, openxml

how can find the numbers of tabs related to paragraphs with openxml in c#?

for example:

```
     test paragraph1
              test paragraph2
```

imagine first paragraph has one tab space and 2nd have two tab space.
i want to find some thing like this with open xml in c#,but how?

is this posts related?

[c-sharp-tab-escape-character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787/c-sharp-tab-escape-character)

[Escape Sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open XMl will use the fallowing xml to include tab in the paragraph

```
<w:r>
  <w:tab />
  <w:t>Paragraph one</w:t>
</w:r>
```

The following code will achieve your requirement in C#:

```
XNamespace W = @"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main";
using (
    WordprocessingDocument document =
        WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"YourDocPath\tabs_in_text.docx", true))
{
    var body = document.MainDocumentPart.Document.GetFirstChild<Body>();
    var paras = body.Elements<Paragraph>();

    foreach (var para in paras)
    {
        //Ver. 1
        //var xml = XElement.Parse(para.OuterXml);
        // var count = xml.Descendants(W + "tab").Count();

        //Ver. 2
        var tabElements = para.Descendants<TabChar>();
        var count = tabElements.Count(); // Collect the counts into array or dictionary for your usage.
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.